# 0cf3:3004 Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth stop working within 5 minutes

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

## System Information

`uname -r`:

```
4.4.0-57-generic
```

---

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:5170 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb` (detailed):

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0cf3 Atheros Communications, Inc.
  idProduct          0x3004 AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
  bcdDevice            0.02
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

---

`rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

**11/01/2017:** Upon Jeremy31's instruction, `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` yields:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [17aa:3803]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
```

---

**11/01/2017:** `usb-devices | awk '/3004/' RS=` yields [as asked by Jeremy (wa113y3s) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1542743/comments/5)]:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=03 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0cf3 ProdID=3004 Rev=00.02
S:  Manufacturer=Atheros Communications
S:  Product=Bluetooth USB Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=Alaska Day 2006
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

This seems to be a non-Rome version according to what Jeremy posted.

---

## Problem Solving

### Default behavior

On fresh boot, I am able to switch on my bluetooth and connect to my  bluetooth speakers. During this time, `systemctl status bluetooth.service` outputs:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-01-05 17:15:22 IST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 894 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─894 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 05 17:15:23 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 05 17:15:23 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 05 17:15:23 z510 bluetoothd[894]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jan 05 17:15:33 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jan 05 17:16:00 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 05 17:16:00 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jan 05 17:16:06 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jan 05 17:16:26 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jan 05 17:16:51 z510 bluetoothd[894]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jan 05 17:16:59 z510 bluetoothd[894]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C6_26_6C_35_6B/fd0: fd(22) ready
```

After about 3 to 4 minutes, bluetooth shows that it's still connected but stops working. At this point, `systemctl status bluetooth.service` returns the exact same output as above. There is nothing new in the above logs.

### Problem Solving

Restarting the bluetooth service via `systemctl restart bluetooth.service` outputs the following in the logs:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-01-05 17:23:44 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 3760 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─3760 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 05 17:23:44 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.55 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

If I try to toggle via taskbar or Bluetooth in the System settings, it doesn't work. This is what I get:

[image: Bluetooth toggle can be toggled but nothing else is usable]

Running `systemctl status bluetooth.service` now shows an error (due to switching the toggle):

```
Jan 05 17:23:55 z510 bluetoothd[3760]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

Next, I check what `hciconfig hci0` has to say:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: A4:DB:30:D1:E5:52  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:115191 acl:36 sco:0 events:15936 errors:0
    TX bytes:9622901 acl:15651 sco:0 commands:280 errors:9
```

Seeing as it is DOWN, I try to start it: `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` and receive the following message:

```
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

Checking the bluetooth service logs again after trying to init `hci0`, there is nothing new.

---

## Solutions Tried

I have tried the following already with little success:

[Pilot6's answer to Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04 with [0cf3:3004] Atheros adapter](https://askubuntu.com/a/791590/431957)
The version mentioned here does not work at all for me. The bluetooth icon disappears from wingpanel and bluetooth itself does not work at all.

Then, I tried version 0.2 (latest revision [here](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth) -- `btusb-lp1653843-dkms`) by Pilot6. This seemed to work at first, but stopped working 3 to 4 minutes later, as it does on an untouched kernel.

I have also disabled Secure Boot (requested when installing `btusb-lp1542743-dkms/0.1`), but that did not help the issue in any way.

**Update 11/01/2017:** However, The behaviour seems to be inconsistent. `btusb-lp1653843-dkms/0.2` worked for a few days (05/01/2017 to 11/01/2017) but stopped working altogether now, after my laptop woke up from sleep.

---

## Links to Related Discussions

There are several discussions regarding this bluetooth chip online but they are beyond my scope:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201646
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/88030/bluetooth-headset-stops-working-suddenly/
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99371
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1542743

---

## Additional Notes

My internal audio has bugged out and the only way to get audio to work is to either connect headphones/speakers via a cable or use bluetooth audio. Both of them work, but I prefer the latter for portability. Currently, I have plugged in the bluetooth speakers via a 3.5mm cable and it works fine. However, I'd still like to be able to use bluetooth and avoid the hassle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: File a bug report against linux as you have an issue different from the 2 bug report links- a sure sign was Pilot6's answer not working.  You likely have an Atheros AR chipset, check `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`  Pilot6's answer would only fix bluetooth on the new QCA chipsets that use the ath10k_pci module

Comment: I have attached the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `usb-devices | awk '/3004/' RS=` to the original question. Please check.

Comment: I have the same issue on my Samsung laptop with AR3012, even updated to kernel 4.9.2 on Loki 0.4 and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @Alex I'm discussing this issue here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350200. Please join. Fixing this might take a long time. If you have the exact same bluetooth+wifi combo, then at least we both could try to solve it. However, if you manage to get it working on eOS, that would be fantastic, since it's my daily-driver too.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Firmware of Atheros (if your adapter is Atheros) and type this command in your terminal:

```
rmmod ath3k && modprobe ath3k
```